# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.wm.util.Strings.isBlank(Ljava/lang/String;)Z

Tags: java, netbeans-8, nosuchmethoderror

I'm facing an odd error, I'm adding a new jar to my java application (using Netbeans) this jar contain a java class called Strings.

When I decompiled this class I found a method called **isBlank().**

But once this jar is add to my librairy and my program  is runned; an ERROR message displayed "**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.wm.util.Strings.isBlank(Ljava/lang/String;)Z**" and I'm pretty sure that that method exist as demonstrate by the attached screensoht[adding jar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHTQl.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed, i found that other JARs contain the same class with different method. So in compilation process the compilator was taking the class from the wrang JAR
Solution : i delete the undesired jar

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. The problem here is that isBlank is only available since Java 11 but in the pom the compiler was set to 8. But since 11 is installed on my local machine I could compile and only noticed the problem later while running my program. I am really unhappy how this works without even a warning.